# Как сделать, чтобы в телеграм боте каждая кнопка была с новой строки?

Tags: python, aiogram

как сделать чтобы кнопки были каждый раз с новой строки?

```py
buttons = ["Мы хотим в первый класс в вашу школу...",
                   "Возможен ли перевод в вашу школу из другой?",
                   "Как происходит прием в классы с углубленным изучением?",
                   "Как организовано питание в школе?",
                   "Как организовано медицинское обслуживание?",
                   "Как осуществляется доступ в школу? Правда ли, что родителям запрещено проходить в школу?",
                   "У нас недопонимание с учителем. Как быть?",
                   "Как узнать отметки ребенка?",
                   "обратно к категориям "]
keyboard.add(*buttons)
```

оформление такое

Answer (score 2):

При создании клавиатуры в `aiogram` можно указать аргумент `row_width`, который определяет сколько кнопок будет на одной строке.

```py
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardMarkup
inline_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1) # инлайн клавиатура
reply_kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1) # реплай клавиатура
```